# Entity Framework Core: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application using Entity Framework Core, and I'm encountering an error when trying to insert data into my database. The error message I'm receiving is:

"SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Items_Orders_OrderID". The conflict occurred in database "OrderEase", table "dbo.Orders", column 'OrderID'."

I have a one-to-many relationship between the Items and Orders tables, where each item is associated with an order. I've checked the following:

- The OrderID values in my dropdown list for creating items correspond
  to valid orders in the Orders table.
- My DbContext class is configured correctly to establish the
  relationship between Item and Order.
- Cascade delete is enabled in my DbContext to ensure that associated
  items are deleted when orders are deleted.

Despite these checks, I'm still encountering this error. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Here's a snippet of my DbContext configuration:

```
// DbContext configuration in OnModelCreating method


modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Items)
    .WithOne(i => i.Order)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderID)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Create (GET) action in the Items Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
 {
     var itemsWithOrders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
     var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
     {
         OrderID = item.OrderID,
     }).ToList();
     ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID");
     return View();
 }
```

Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot: SQL Exception]

Comment: The error basically says, that `item` you are saving has no `OrderID` value or has `OrderID` value which does not exists. It doesn't satisfy DB scheme, in which every item must be linked to existing order via foreign key. Have you tried to debug your code and what is `OrderID` value of `item` being saved?

Comment: There is a dropdown list in the Create view for Items, with a list of all OrderIDs to associate an item with an Order. So, I can confirm that only valid OrderIDs are being populated in the Dropdown list.

Comment: In dropdown yes, but what is `OrderID` value here, in the code, right where exception is thrown?

Comment: For instance there is an OrderID '1004' for the first order in my Orders table. Creating an item I select the same OrderID '1004' from a Dropdown list to associate that item with an existing order. I hope I am making sense

Comment: I understand dropdown and interface part, just trying to eliminate potential data binding issue before going to EF part. Could you please set a breakpoint right on the line where you have exception and show field values of `item`?

Comment: Oh I see what you're talking about now.  So how can I ensure that the existing OrderIDs are being  added when creating an item? The OrderID value is 0

Comment: So I changed to an existing OrderID and a record was inserted successfully. How can I get this done automatically?

Comment: So EF is not the problem here, and the question is not about EF. I would suggest to edit the question (or better create a new one  about UI part), and provide code snippets, which do the data binding from UI.

Comment: So in the end the only problem is that the OrderID isn't set in `item`, which is a UI issue. All answers here are premature and can be deleted.

Comment: In other words, when You select an OrderID in your dropdown list, You should read the selected value in **ViewBag.OrderIDList.OrderID**

Answer (score 1):

Your are adding a new child **Item**, which has both **OrderId=0** and **Order class null** (parent class). So, if the order already exists (like I think), You should put at least, in this new Item's OrderId property (foreign key), a valid value pointing to your order row (existing in the Orders table).

Comment: That is already being done through a Dropdown list populated with existing OrderIDs

Answer (score 0):

If you have both an OrderId and an Order (which it seems so from your question) properties in your item class then it can be confusing which one EF is going to use when inserting your item.

I think the best practice is to always set the Order property rather than the OrderId.

Comment: This ""FK_Items_Orders_OrderID"" is a FOREIGN KEY constraint  designed to maintain referential integrity between the two tables. It enforces that values in the "OrderID" column of the "Items" table must correspond to valid values in the "OrderID" column of the "Orders" table.  This has been fulfilled by the dropdown list with a list of existing OrderIDs. What else do I need to check?

Comment: How is the Item instance created? Can you log the values that it has in all the properties before trying to save it?

Answer (score 0):

When adding Items to a parent, in this case `Order`, EF gives you a number of options.

1. Add the new `Item` to the parent object's collection property, this will assign the `OrderID` from the parent when the parent record is saved.

   - DO NOT add the item to the context directly if you are using this object assignment
2. Update the `Item` with the `OrderID` from the parent object, then you can add the item to the context directly.

   - Avoid assigning the parent object via the `item. Order` navigation property when adding to the context directly as it can result in duplicate isnerts of the parent object.

So with EF, you must choose, are you assigning Foreign Key values and Adding or updating directly to the context, or are you loading the parent from the context, with existing items, and adding the object refrences to the parent object rather than to the context DbSet?

Your code uses option 2, but the error indicates that you haven't assigned the `item.OrderID` to match the parent `Order`. Set this first and the insert will likely work. It is not clear from you code example where the current or selected *Order* might come from so I can't offer you a code solution.

> **NOTE:**
> Option 2 doesn't work if the parent record has not yet been created in the database. So if the parent `Order` already exists, then this option can work for you  but using the Option 1 to assign objects via navigation properties means you can create and update nested object graphs and save them to the database and have EF manage the FK IDs for you.

Comment: Hi Chris. Please check the  post, I added the Create (GET) action which is where I retrieve the OrderIDs in the Items Create.

Comment: @Blessing You still haven't shown how the item gets assigned the `OrderID`, it only shows how you are loading the order IDs into the view. When you create the item, I am expecting the item value posted back to the controller to already have the `OrderID` selected, so you will need to show the view code as well.

Comment: I’ll add in the code snippet just now